# deferring exiting on --help when using parse_known_args()

Tags: python, argparse

I have a code that needs to build its command line arguments dynamically, based on configuration file. Schematically, what I end up doing is

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--config", type=str, default="",
                        help="Path to config file.")
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

#here do stuff with args.config to extend parser list of arguments, and then:

parser.parse_args()
```

The argument management seems to work perfectly well but the trouble I have is that `--help` will exit at the first call `parse_known_args`, instead of the second `parser.parse_args()` which would have shown all the dynamically added arguments.... Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: With the default `add_help=True`, a `help` argument is created, and will always act, including with `parse_known_args`.  `parse_args` is just `parse_known_args` with a different way handling the `unknown`.  You could create the parser without that `add_help`.  But then you won't get any help - unless you add your own `help` argument later.  May be you should make two parsers, one without the help that reads the config, and other with a regular help.

Comment: yes it seems to be a way out, to create two parsers, namely `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)` first, and after the args have been dynamically added `parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(parser, add_help=True)` . Thanks @hpaulj

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some time ago. It can be solved by using two parsers.

- A first pre-parser, with [`add_help=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help) to determine the configuration file;
- The second full parser with help.

```py
# test.py
import argparse

# First pre-parser to determine the configuration file
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--config", default="", help="Path to config file.")
args = parser.parse_known_args()

# Do something with args.config

# Full and real parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--config", default="", help="Path to config file.")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--option", help="Option with default value from config file")

parser.parse_args()
```

This result in:

```
$ python3 test.py --help
usage: test.py [-h] [-c CONFIG] [-o OPTION]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c CONFIG, --config CONFIG
                        Path to config file.
  -o OPTION, --option OPTION
                        Option with default value from config file
```

Comment: thanks. Yes it is exactly what I came up with.